# Visual Basic: Get sql error output from WebBrowser

Tags: php, vb.net

How can I get SQL error output from WebBrouser and put it in RichTextBox1
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general programming question and thus belongs to StackOverflow